# Minimize function with many parameters

Tags: python, variables, optimization, minimize

I want to minimize a function in order to obtain some parameters' value of : a,e,I,Omega,om,tp.

I use this "module" : docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html.

My function has 13 parameters:

[image: Function I want to reduce]

I imported : `from scipy.optimize import minimize`. Then I try to minimize it.And  the error occurs:

[image: Minimize code + error message]

Would someone help to solve this problem?

PS: I started python one week ago that may explain this syntax of the program, however I'm willing to improve myself.

```
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
from os import chdir
chdir("/Users/benjaminjaillant/Desktop")

def Chi_VLT(a,e,I,tp,Omega,om,Mbh,R0,Vr_bh,alpha_bh,V_alp_bh,delta_bh,V_del_bh):
    return sum(((Vr_etoile(t_vr_VLT*365*24*3600,a,e,I,tp,om,Mbh,Vr_bh)/1000)-vr_VLT)**2/vr_error_VLT**2) + sum(((alpha_etoile_IR(t_orbit_VLT*365*24*3600,a,e,I,tp,Omega,om,Mbh,alpha_bh,V_alp_bh,R0)*206264806.246)-Ra_VLT)**2/Ra_error_VLT**2) + sum(((delta_etoile_IR(t_orbit_VLT*365*24*3600,a,e,I,tp,Omega,om,Mbh,delta_bh,V_del_bh,R0)*206264806.246)-Dec_VLT)**2/Dec_error_VLT**2)


x0 = [1.5e14,0.8,2.5,63.10e9,4,1,8.5e36,2.5e20,2000,1.3e-8,-10e-18,2e-9,1.5e-17]

res = minimize(Chi_VLT, x0 , method='nelder-mead',options={'xtol': 1e-4,'maxiter':50 ,'disp': True})

print res.message
print res.x
```

Comment: Hello to all :) , i dont know how edit my post ..

Comment: Î just here, below the tags, please post the code of your function, not a picture

Comment: all the code ?? It wouldn't be too complicated for you to read it ?

Comment: we only need the relevant and reproducible part here

Comment: from the looks of it the optimizer is trying to call the function with the single argument x0 (a list...) rather than its contents. You could try converting x0 into an nd-array of the desired type first.

Comment: Make Chi_VLT only taking one parameter, some vector, which you can unpack to all your values at the top of the function.

Comment: as i can see, the problem is your function, how it is possible to have so many arguments ? consider reading this too https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/

Comment: thx for your answers but if i make Chi_VLT taking one parameter, it leads me to other problem.. 
How can i convert x0 " into an nd-array of the desired type first "?

Answer (score 0):

The minimize routine expects an ndarray, say `guess`, as initial function arguments and accepts an additional tuple of arguments x0 which might constitute the coefficients in your cost function. If you rewrite CHI_VLT to take as first arg an ndarray and then the remaining arguments accordingly it should work.

```
res = minimize(CHI_VLT, guess, args=x0,...)
```

Comment: Thanks mate, i tried but now here's the problem :
 TypeError: minimize() takes at most 12 arguments (16 given)
I just don't get how works python.. !

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are messing with whole thing here.

your function `scipy.optimize.minimize` takes two required positional argument,
 `fun` and `x0`.

you need `ndarray` as `x0`

In your case your fun `Chi_VLT` requires 13 arguments, you need to pass that using `args=(tuple, containing, 13, items)`

Then only you will be able to minimize your fun.

Comment: thanks, you mean i have to write : minimize(Chi_VLT, x0 , args=(a,e,I...(13paramters)) , method='nelder-mead' ) ?

Comment: Yes. x0 is okay. It can be list, like what you have.

Comment: I wrote : 
    

x0 = (1.5e14,0.8,2.5,63.10e9,4,1,8.5e36,2.5e20,2000,1.3e-8,-10e-18,2e-9,1.5e-17)
  
  
res = minimize(Chi_VLT, x0 , args=(a,e,I,tp,Omega,om,Mbh,R0,Vr_bh,alpha_bh,V_alp_bh,delta_bh,V_del_bh) ,method='nelder-mead',options={'xtol': 1e-4,'maxiter':50 ,'disp': True})

It still doesn't work, according to the program "a","e".. are not defined